# How to search for all text lines that start with a tab character?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, search, grep

I need to find all lines in a text file that start with a tab character.

I tried this command:

`findstr /B /R "\t" test.txt`

But it doesn't print any lines.

I also tried with `grep.exe` (taken from [UnxUtils](https://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/)):

`grep -E "^\t" test.txt`

This also doesn't print any lines.

Comment: Try escaping the ``\`` - `findstr /B /R "\\t" test.txt`

Comment: @DavidPostill I've just tried that, but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I need to find all lines in a text file that start with <kbd>tab</kbd>.

You need to start `cmd` with the `/f:on` parameter. This changes the file completion character to <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> and frees up <kbd>tab</kbd> so you can use it on the command line.

```
cmd /f:on
```

See: [CMD.exe (Command Shell) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)

You also need to use `findstr` with `/c` not `/r`

Example:

```
F:\test>type tab.txt
        this line starts with a tab
        this line starts with spaces
F:\test>findstr /b /c:" " tab.txt
        this line starts with a tab
```

where: the character in quotes above is <kbd>tab</kbd> not <kbd>space</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

For those of us who use Powershell, it can be achieve with the cmdlet:

```ps
 Select-String test.txt -Pattern "^\t.+"
```

This will show the lines and indicates the line number. If you don't want to see the line numbers, use the following:

```ps
 Select-String test.txt -Pattern "^\t.+" -Raw
```